# How do I get the user's age in years

Tags: javascript, date, browser, geolocation, ecma

I would like to use `Geolocation` and `Date` in JavaScript (ECMA) to ask the user **where** and when they were born and convert this into years. I am asking where they were born because I need to take into account different time zones.

So far, my function returns the number of years the user is old:

```
function birth() {
  var their_birth_day = new Date("18 May 2005"); // Just as an example
  var today = new Date();

  var ms_old = today.getTime() - their_birth_day.getTime();
  var yrs_old = ms_old/3.154e+10;
  return yrs_old;
}
```

But how do I use their location to make it more accurate?

Comment: can you explain more ?

Comment: also please tell me what yrs_old expression is

Comment: Why do you need Geolocation API in order to get the place where the user was born? You mentioned Time zones, you can use Date().getTimezoneOffset()

Comment: @Tunjay Maybe I don't, I just need a way to get around time zone differences making my yrs_old variable imprecise.

Comment: @me.nkr yrs_old is **the amount of time between the user's birthday and today**, measured in years. In other words, the age of the user. I have not rounded it but I would round it to say 3 decimal places (but ignore this as this is not important for this question).

Comment: Why consider the timezone offset for a birthday if you don't consider the time of birth? [Creating a date for a specific location](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+create+date+for+timezone) has been covered in other questions. Timezone offsets are generally ignored when dealing with dates without times, like birthdays.

Comment: @RobG I would use a date, and several other factors but I have overlooked them in this condensed example.

Answer (score -1):

```
function getAge( dateString ) {
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
    return age;
}
```